# AES Encrypt in PHP to decrypt in openssl

Tags: php

```
set_include_path('./phpseclib0.2.1a'); //http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/
include('Crypt/AES.php');

$plaintext = 'PLAINTEXT';

$aes = new Crypt_AES(CRYPT_AES_MODE_CBC);
$aes->setKey('1234123412341234');
$ciphertext = $aes->encrypt($plaintext);
$fp = fopen("ciphertextAES", "wb");
fwrite($fp, $ciphertext);
fclose($fp);


---------------------------

openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -d -in ciphertextAES -out plaintext.txt -pass pass:1234123412341234 -nosalt
bad decrypt ?????????????????????????
3840:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:.\crypto\evp\evp_enc.c:466:
```

Comment: Is there a question that comes with that piece of code? What are you trying to do? Please be more descriptive so we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -e -in plaintext.txt -out ciphertext -nosalt -K AA
-iv AA -p
```

`-p` shows you the key and IV being used:

```
key=AA000000000000000000000000000000
iv =AA000000000000000000000000000000
```

Omit the `-K` and the `-iv` parameters and use `-pass`, instead, and you'll see that the password and the key are not at all the same thing. This is true regardless of whether or not the `-nosalt` option is used.